# How to make the sitemap.xml visible in google search result? I have submitted it on Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I noticed that even after submitting the sitemap on Google Webmaster Console, it is still not showing up on google search.

Comment: As Rob said, this should not be visible in search results.

Comment: I think it is likely that the person who asked this question means that the pages in the site map are not indexed yet.

Answer (score 3):

sitemap.xml is for search engines to find pages on your site and is not for public viewing in search results.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned in the answers and comments the sitemap itself will not show on in the Google search results as it is a tool to list all of the pages in your site to assist with indexing your site. If you are referring to the pages themselves that are identified in the sitemap file not showing in Google yet then this can take some time. Having content added to the Google index, even after submitting a sitemap is not a real time process, submitting your sitemap helps Google discover and index your pages but it can take anywhere up to 2+ weeks for the content to show up in the Google index. Using webmaster tools you can see how many pages from your site have been indexed and this will give you an indication as to how completely your site has been crawled and indexed but there is no way to accelerate the process beyond what Google algorithms determine is the ideal crawl rate for your site.